# compare graph structure using java

Tags: java, graph, compare

I am implementing a schema matching algorithm.I need to perform schema structure matching, i need to represent schema as a is-a has-a relationship graph....one graph per schema...
each node in relation model will represent a table with is-a as table and one has-a relationship for each column(having there own is-a).
My question is how to implement this in best way using java, comparing  graphs will be pseudo polynomial in graph size and may through out of memory error if we pull complete schema..i want to find nodes with similar relationships in both graphs ( this will lead to DFS)
is there any already existing java implementation that can do this, i already explored jgraphT, jung...not sure which one will be best to do this..please help

thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever graph API you use ought to allow you to do something like this:

```
boolean equal = graph1.equals(graph2);
```

where that evaluates true if the nodesets and edgesets are equal. The nodes would need IDs or else content so you could establish actual equality as opposed to graph isomorphism.

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: thanks for replying...yes using this i can very well implement what i want...but i want an already existing implementation which given two graphs can tell me which nodes are same in two graphs( should consider all child nodes too under that node)...effectively it should return me a pair of equal subgraphs from two input graphs...i know its asking for too much :D..but just trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.. as I will be working on this task 2 weeks down the line...